# CallGraph Recorder in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, callstack

Is there a way we can instrument Tomcat to record CallGraph of the web application?

I've been trying to get this using visualvm,jconsole but that won't help since they give many information like number of threads, heap memory,..etc.

But my focus is only on the callgraph of the application.

Thanks.

Comment: I came across this Eclipse profiler plugin in https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsecolorer/ will try out that.

Comment: After a bit of searching came across this also http://profiler4j.sourceforge.net/ which will help see the callgraph.